# Load XML data with same value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me to load the following XML into my SQL Server database:

```
declare @learnxml varchar(5000);

set @learnxml = '
      <alerts>
          <alert id="XYQ">
             <alertTime>2020-01-06T09:49:59.999-0500</alertTime> 
           <participants>
                  <item marketCode="CC">MAIN</item>
                  <item marketCode="CC">PASS</item>
           </participants>
        </alert>
     </alerts>'; 

DECLARE @xml XML = @learnxml 
PRINT @learnxml; 

SELECT 
    xData.value('../../@id','Varchar(100)') AlertId,
    xData.value('../../alertTime[1]','Varchar(50)') AlertTime,
    xData.value('../item[1]', 'varchar(50)') ParticipantHouse,
    xData.value('(.)/@marketCode', 'varchar(20)') HouseMarketCode 
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('./alerts/alert/participants/item') AS x(xData)
```

Because of the same market code for both the items, the above query populates same value 'Main' instead of populating 2 rows with 2 different values Main and Pass.

What needs to be changed in above query to have 2 different values for the same market code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query returns correct values:

```
SELECT xData.value('../../@id','Varchar(100)') AlertId,
xData.value('../../alertTime[1]','Varchar(50)') AlertTime,
xData.value('.', 'varchar(50)') ParticipantHouse,
xData.value('@marketCode', 'varchar(20)') HouseMarketCode 
FROM @xml.nodes('./alerts/alert/participants/item') as  x(xData)
```